# Wordpress Responsive Widget Containers

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design, widget, customization

I've got a pretty specific issue I'm running into and the theme developer has gone MIA.

I have linked a screencap of what the issue is and I'll try and describe it as best as possible here, too. If more info is needed, just let me know and I'll provide as much as possible.

Screencap: http://tinypic.com/r/53le1l/8

I'm using a pretty modified version of this theme, but nothing that should have an affect on the functionality of the theme:

http://www.themes.red-sun-design.com/?theme=lemonchili

As you can see - the homepage is designed to display widgets, each in their own container, as opposed to a custom page layout (we're ignoring the top slider as that isn't an issue). The widgets that are included in the theme work just fine and size correctly with whatever content is displayed.

homepage layer structure is (from back to front): background image --> sidebar/menu & page background--> page content (slider and widgets)

The issue is, with third-party widgets/plugins and pretty much any interactive content, those containers do not expand correctly and end up leaving the majority of the content not visible.

I'm using the plugin EventON (www.myeventon.com) and if a month has 2 events, as shown in the screencap, it displays fine.  (NOTE: when an event is clicked/selected a lightbox pops up with event info - this isn't an issue)  But if a month has 2+ events, the box resizes to display the info, but does not resize to fit everything else on the page.

If you look at the original theme demo, each box has spacing between each widget.

When you look at the screencap, you'll see that the spacing goes away and the extra events are (I'm assuming) being displayed underneath the widget below the eventON widget.

What I need is to make each of those containers responsive to the content that is being displayed in each one, regardless of the placement on the page while maintaining the same spacing between each widget container.  Also, the actual page background needs to expand to meet content too, which doesn't seem to happen.

I've been trying to find a fix for about a week and am completely stuck.
Does all of that make sense - if this is confusing or if I'm not explaining it correctly, let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? You can try removing `overflow:hidden` from your `.widget` CSS. No idea if that's actually the problem.

Comment: Just tried all options with that.  None of those solved the issue - in fact, any option other than :hidden makes less content visible.

Comment: It looks like your widget or event has a set height with overflow:hidden since the Get Social widget doesn't move when items disappear. just switch it to overflow-y:auto and check the children to see if they have a hidden overflow too. A higher min-height on that widget might help you too.

Answer (score 0):

The template has a very stiff design because each content div section (Hours, Latest Images, Lunch Special, Next Event, The Latest, and About) are absolutely positioned within the container div, and as far as I can tell, overflowing content is even hidden at the bottom of the main content section.

Using the Red Sun Themes as an example: You are correct, the overflowing contents from the "Latest Images" section (where you have your plugin) is displaying underneath the "Next Event" section.

1. One quick solution is to give the "Latest Images" div (this is the one that holds your plugin) a higher z-index than "Next Event". That way, it will display on top of "Next Event", instead of underneath it. Luckily the plugin isn't overflowing by much. Remember to give a z-index to all 3 divs in the column. Example: z-index:10; for "Latest Images", z-index:9; for "Next Event", and z-index:8; for the bottom "About" div.
2. Next size the height of your div to always have enough room for the plugin. Min-width may work well.
3. Then move "Next Event" a few pixels down so the overflow from "Latest Images" won't overlap its top. You'll probably have to move "About" down too.
4. Once you move the other 2 divs down, the bottom div might push past the bottom of the container, and its bottom contents may be hidden. One solution is to decrease the height of the divs by reducing font sizes/padding... Another solution is to increase the height of the main div that's directly under the container div. It looks like the height is in the html code too.
5. Note: From this end it appears that the template holds the div styles in the html code, so you may have to make your adjustments (z-index, top positioning) there.

Another solution would be to add a scrollbar (add width, and overflow:auto;) to the "Latest Images" section, so when the plugin overflowed, there would be a scrollbar. But then the content area would be effected by the size of the scrollbar.